# Build dependencies with TeamCity

Tags: teamcity

I have to build: Internet & Common. I would like that when I click on "Run" for the "Internet" build that the "Common" build executes first.

Is it possible ? I saw artifact dependencies, but I don't need any data to be copied, I just want to build "Common" before "Internet" every time a build for "Internet" is requested.

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at snapshot dependencies, they can trigger a build the same as artifact dependencies but don't necessarily produce artifacts, and can trigger the Common build every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they're using the same VCS root, then configuring a snapshot dependency between the "Internet" build configuration and the "Common" build configuration will enable you to do that; this basically ensures that all the dependencies are built from the same snapshot of the VCS.

If you **must** have the "Common" build execute regardless of its current state, then uncheck the default 'Do not run new build if there is a suitable one' option.  This will ensure "Common" is run every time you hit Run on "Internet".